# Checking and altering value of next line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
32.0.191.171
64
32
128.1.1.1
128
64
128
97.4.100.3
32
```

and it should look like this (The file contains IPs and numbers. Every IP should be followed by exactly one number, not more. If an IP is followed by two or more numbers the IP and the numbers should be deleted):

```
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
97.4.100.3
32
```

I tried some code with awk (get line, prev), but unfortunately could´t get it done. I don't know if it helps, but I think this code should identify the IP:

```
awk --re-interval '{
    if ($0 ~ /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/) 
    { 

    } 
    }'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/! { H; $!d; }; x; //!d; /\n.*\n/d' filename
```

This keeps in the hold buffer the last found IP address and the lines that come after it until the next IP address or end of file is found, then checks whether there's more than two lines in it and prints or discards the block accordingly.

LIne by line:

```
# If there is no IP address in the current line (note the ! after the condition)
/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/! {

  # append the line to the hold buffer.
  H

  # and unless it is the last one, continue with the next line, not printing
  # anything.
  $!d
}

# We only get here if there was an IP address or this is the last line. Swap in
# the remembered things from the hold buffer (placing the IP address in the hold
# buffer at the same time)
x

# If there's no IP address in the stuff we swapped in (// reattempts the last
# regex, which is the IP regex, and that there isn't one happens the very first
# time we get here), discard it.
//!d

# If there are two newlines in it, discard it also.
/\n.*\n/d

# Otherwise we drop off here and it is printed.
```

Comment: thank you very much - also for your detailed description - it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The following matches lines with `.` and starts to accumulate the lines in variable `acc`. Other lines get concatenated onto the variable with an intervening newline. At the end, or when a line has a `.`, if the `acc` variable has exactly 1 newline (ie splits into 2 parts), it is printed.
Pipe your data into it.

```
awk '/\./{ if(split(acc,x,"\n")==2)print acc; acc = $1; next }
         { acc = acc "\n" $0 }
      END{ if(split(acc,x,"\n")==2)print acc }'
```

Answer (score 1):

A perl way:

```
$/=undef;
my $str = <DATA>;
$str =~ s/\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\R(?:\d+\R){2,}//g;
say $str;

__DATA__
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
32.0.191.171
64
32
128.1.1.1
128
64
128
97.4.100.3
32
```

**Output:**

```
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
97.4.100.3
32
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `perl` approach - I know you already have one, but this takes a different angle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $current_buffer = '';
my $notip = 0;
while (<>) {
    if ( my ($ip) = m/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$/ ) {
        if ( $notip <= 1 ) { print $current_buffer; }
        $current_buffer = $ip . "\n";
        $notip          = 0;
    }
    else {
        $notip++;
        $current_buffer .= $_;
    }
}

print $current_buffer if $notip <= 1;
```

Builds up a buffer as it's processing, and 'flushes' or 'discards' the buffer depending on how many numbers follow it.

Answer (score 0):

This Perl solution works in a different way. It reads the input one line at a time, and starts a new block in `@blocks` every time a line containing a dot is encountered. That has the result of splitting the input into blocks of lines each starting with an IP address

Then those accumulated blocks that have exactly two lines are printed out

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @blocks;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    push @blocks, [ ] if /\./;
    push @{ $blocks[-1] }, $_;
}

for my $block ( @blocks ) {
  print @$block if @$block == 2;
}

__DATA__
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
32.0.191.171
64
32
128.1.1.1
128
64
128
97.4.100.3
32
```

#### output

```
1.0.0.2
32
255.0.0.6
0
97.4.100.3
32
```